# php login: issue with header

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, header, mysqli

I'm trying to make a login page using php, but when I use header() to redirect to another page, my user/pass check on my database somehow fails. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I know I'm missing security guards, I'm implementing in steps since I'm still rather new to PHP. But some tips and suggestions would be appreciated!

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'wamad')
or die("Error connecting to MySQL server.");

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password';";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die("Login error");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

header("Location:login_success.php");
}else{
    echo "Wrong username or password.";
}

echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the semicolon. And I never used a `die();` after sending a header and it always worked fine.

Are you sending some output to the browser before you're sending the header? If that is the case your header won't be set. Are you displaying PHP errors? Do you have an error log? Are there errors showing up?

Additionally, headers should always end with a linebreak, so send `header ("Location: login_success.php\n");`

Comment: No, I don't output anything prior to sending a header. The issue is mainly with mysqli_num_row($result). When I include the header, it doesn't find my query, otherwise it works fine. 

Can you also explain why headers should always end with a linebreak?

Comment: Linebreaks seperate the header fields. Do you get any error messages in the error_log?

Comment: nvm on the error, I know what I was doing wrong...silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% positive what you're trying to do, but typically you need to kill the script after using the location header.

```
header('Location: login_success.php');
die();
```

Otherwise the script continues to run after setting the header.

Comment: I'm trying to check if a user login attempt is valid or not. When I don't have the header() line, it works fine, but when it's included, it doesn't seem to check properly against my db. I print out the search query for user/pass and I get a 0 when that line's included.